# sums based on criteria in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My sheet has two main tables. Part of them are:

First table:
[image: Table 1]

Second Table:
[image: Table 2]

My goal is to find total penalty for each drive in table 2. For example, from the second table we can see that Disk drive 1 has data sets 1, 2 and 4. So the total penalty for Drive 1 should be the sum of penalties for having sets 1 and 2,1 and 4 and 2 and 4 (so from the first table, the penalty value corresponding to 1 and 2 i.e.57, 1 and 4 i.e. 57 and 2 and 4 which is 113). If there were more sets in Drive 1, then we would want to add the relevant combinations from table 1. Please ignore the megabyte column in second table, as it is not relevant to any calculation

How do I find the sum for penalties for each drive in such scenarios from these two tables? It has got me pretty stumped. Any help will be appreciated. :)

Comment: Could you please provide calculations for Drive 2 for example? Just it has obly 1 record in table 2, so it's not clear how to calculate

Comment: In a similar vein to Mixaz's question: What happens if a disk has three data sets associated with it?

Comment: @Mixaz Calculations for drive 2 will be the same. Since there are 10 data sets and only 3 drives to  put them in, each drive will have multiple data sets and the penalties would be calculated based on data from table 1. Does that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I clearly understand your problem and I would like to propose you a solution without writing any VBA code.

Please note that it will work only if data set column in your second table contains unique values (but if not, it should not be difficult to find a workaround).

You may add a column for every drive you have in your First table after Penalty column, as I did in the picture here below:

[image]

In every row you will compare first set and second set values with your second table. If they both have the Disk drive value equal to the one in column of the cell, you will mark as TRUE, otherwise as FALSE.

The formula for the cell is this one (let's take D4 in my picture as reference and your Second table):

```
=IFERROR(IF(AND(INDEX('Second table'!$E$4:$G$8,MATCH(A4,'Second table'!$E$4:$E$8,0),3)=D$3, INDEX('Second table'!$E$4:$G$8,MATCH(B4,'Second table'!$E$4:$E$8,0),3)=D$3)=TRUE, TRUE, FALSE),FALSE)
```

You will have to adapt this formula to real references in your document.

Once your formula is ready you can copy in all cells of every disk drive column up to the end of the table.

You can now very easily use a SUMIF to calculate the sum of penalties for each Disk Drive. In my table here above I put this formula in cell D16:

```
=SUMIF(D4:D14,"TRUE",C4:C14)
```

If I did not get the sense of your question, do not hesitate to comment my post!